# Python CSV writerows and List comprehension

Tags: python, csv

I have the following structure, I need to save it with csv.writerows() hence I want to have a list of lists.

Each element is a dictionary (key + list) which I need to unpack and then convert it to a list of lists.

```
  results = [{'06079467037ACD8AMV': ['US', 'IT', 3065, 'NOT_FOUND']}, {'A557288EDE635FD6MV': ['US', 'Cars 3', 2604, 'NOT_FOUND']}, {'0367F463382D27FBMV': ['US', 'Kingsman: The Golden Circle', 1580, 'NOT_FOUND']}]
```

Example:

```
[['06079467037ACD8AMV', 'US', 'IT', 3065, 'NOT_FOUND'], ['A557288EDE635FD6MV', 'US', 'Cars 3', 2604, 'NOT_FOUND'], ['0367F463382D27FBMV', 'US', 'Kingsman: The Golden Circle', 1580, 'NOT_FOUND']]
```

Any idea?
I tried the following code with no luck:

```
 [[k]+v for k,v in movie.iteritems() for movie in results]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have your list comprehension clauses backwards:

```
[[k]+v for movie in results for k,v in movie.iteritems()]
```